# Spyder won't launch after conda install -c conda-forge opencv

Tags: python, opencv, conda, spyder

I have installed `opencv` by the following command:

```
conda install -c conda-forge opencv
```

My environment is python 3.5 and spyder 3.3. All other packages come with installation of anaconda and updating of conda.

It is clear that the `opencv` installation gives the `spyder` launching error!

Comment: Have you tried to run it directly through the `spyder` terminal command

Comment: I have tried: spyder --new-instance. It does not work

Answer (score 0):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) Conda-forge and the defaults Anaconda packages are binary incompatible and that's the source of this problem.

To fix this problem you need to:

1. Reinstall Anaconda (your command above simply broke it).
2. Install conda-forge packages in a dedicated environment, with this command:

   `conda create -n cf -c conda-forge opencv`
3. Follow [our guide](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/wiki/Working-with-packages-and-environments-in-Spyder) to learn how to work with that environment.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with you so that found this post.

I was trying to follow the answer given by Carlos Cordoba. However, surprisingly after I reinstalled the Anaconda, and installed the opencv package with

conda install -c conda-forge opencv

Then open Spyder import cv2

It works without going through the guidance

Answer (score 0):

For me calling:

```
conda update conda
```

in environment solved this problem.